# Howto install gcc on NetBSD 6.1.2?

Tags: gcc, netbsd

I did a minimal install of NetBSD 6.1.2 and thought it would be easy to install a working gcc package. But even after `pkg_add -r gcc48 gcc48-libs` and adding gcc to the path, gcc is still not able to compile simple programs.

Which packages do I need and which additional config steps are necessary ?

Comment: If you installed the `comp` package, you should have gcc. You say that "gcc is still not able to compile simple programs." What does that mean? What errors do you encounter?

Comment: pkg_add didn't find a 'comp' package. One error I'm getting from including stdio.h that sys/cdefs.h is missing.

Comment: It's not a pkg_add package. It's one of the system packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the `comp` package did the trick and added gcc 4.5.3.

```
tar -C / -xpzf /path/to/comp.tgz
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You installed system gcc compiler. Your original question was how to install gcc-4.8xx. If you are using pkgsrc the easiest thing is

```
cd /usr/pkgsrc/lang/gcc48
make install clean clean-depens
```

Note that NetBSD has multiple versions of gcc compiler the 2.9.5 probably the most useful and the last truly portable gcc version. The first place to check 
for pkgsrc package is

[pkgsrc.se](http://pkgsrc.se/)

you also want to read documentation on pkgsrc

http://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/index.html

NetBSD also has new binary packaging system pkgin  which is very similar to Yum and apt-get but I am not a regular NetBSD user so you would want to check documentation how to use pkgng

Comment: Any gcc version is fine by me. At first I didn't realize there are so many versions to choose from. Thanks for your explanation for gcc 4.8!